# Error using react-leaflet and react-testing-library: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-leaflet

I am using Jest and react-testing-library to test a Create-React-App project (TS) that uses Redux Toolkit for state management and react-leaflet for mapping. I am encountering an error when attempting to render components that have the  component down the tree.

Example test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderWithProviders } from '../renderWithProviders';
import { ForestMap } from '../../Containers/Dashboard/ForestMap';
import { mockServer } from '../mockServer';

beforeAll(() => mockServer.listen());
afterEach(() => mockServer.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => mockServer.close());

describe('ForestMap', () => {

  test('display map on successful response', async () => {
    renderWithProviders(<ForestMap />);

  });
});
```

ForestMap.tsx:

```
/*eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*/
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { TileLayer, MapContainer, FeatureGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { EditControl } from 'react-leaflet-draw';
import { LatLng, LatLngBounds, LatLngExpression, Point, PointExpression,
  FeatureGroup as LeafletFeatureGroup } from 'leaflet';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../Redux/hooks';
import { useGetForestsQuery } from '../../Redux/api';
import { Forest } from '../Forests/forestTypes';
import { setSelectedForests, setShapeBoundState } from './ForestMapSlice';
import ForestMarker from './ForestMarker';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

const pointInPoly = require('point-in-polygon');//eslint-disable-line

const mapToken = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN;

const zoomValue = 9;

export const ForestMap = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { bounds, radius, centerPnt, polyPnts,
    selectedForest } = useAppSelector((state) => state.forestMap);
  const { data } = useGetForestsQuery();
  const featureGroupRef = useRef<LeafletFeatureGroup>(null);  

  const onCreate = (e: any) => {//eslint-disable-line
    const currentLayers = featureGroupRef.current?.getLayers();
    if (currentLayers && currentLayers.length > 1){
      featureGroupRef.current?.removeLayer(currentLayers[0]);
    }
    
    if (e.layerType === 'rectangle'){
      const rectBounds: LatLngBounds = e.layer.getBounds() as LatLngBounds;      
      dispatch(setShapeBoundState({ bounds: rectBounds }));
    }
  
    if (e.layerType === 'polygon'){
      const polyLatLngs = e.layer._latlngs[0] as LatLng[];
      const polyPoints = polyLatLngs.map(Object.values) as unknown as LatLng[];
      dispatch(setShapeBoundState({ polyPnts: [...polyPoints] }));
    }
  
    if (e.layerType === 'circle'){
      const center: Point = e.layer.getLatLng() as Point;//eslint-disable-line
      const rad: number = e.layer.getRadius() as number;//eslint-disable-line
      dispatch(setShapeBoundState({ centerPnt: center, radius: rad }));
    }
    
  };  

  const onDelete = (e: any) => {//eslint-disable-line
    dispatch(setSelectedForests({ selectedForests: [] }));
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (bounds && data){
      const rectSelected: Forest[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1){
        const { coordinates } = data[i].geom;
        if (bounds.contains([coordinates[1], coordinates[0]] as LatLngExpression)){
          rectSelected.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      dispatch(setSelectedForests({ selectedForets: rectSelected }));
    }    
  }, [bounds, data]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (polyPnts && data){
      const circleSelected: Forest[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1){
        const { coordinates } = data[i].geom;
        if (pointInPoly([coordinates[1], coordinates[0]] as LatLngExpression, polyPnts)){
          circleSelected.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      dispatch(setSelectedForests({ selectedForests: circleSelected }));
    }
  }, [data, polyPnts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (centerPnt && radius && data){
      const polySelected: Forest[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1){
        const { coordinates } = data[i].geom;
        if (data[i] && centerPnt.distanceTo([coordinates[1], coordinates[0]] as PointExpression) < radius){
          polySelected.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      dispatch(setSelectedForests({ selectedForests: polySelected }));
    }
  }, [centerPnt, radius, data]);
  
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
      <MapContainer
        zoom={zoomValue}
        center={[34.0522, -118.2437]}
        scrollWheelZoom
        style={{ height: '60vh', width: '100%' }}
        zoomControl
        >
          <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${mapToken}`}
              no-wrap/>
          <FeatureGroup ref={featureGroupRef}>
              <EditControl
                position='topright'
                onCreated={onCreate}
                onDeleted={onDelete}
                draw={{
                  polygon: true,
                  rectangle: true,
                  polyline: false,
                  circle: true,
                  circlemarker: false,
                  marker: false,
                }}
                />
          </FeatureGroup>
          {data?.map((forest) => {
            const lat = forest.geom.coordinates[1];
            const lng = forest.geom.coordinates[0];
            return (<ForestMarker key={forest.id} id={forest.id as string} coords={[lat, lng] as LatLngExpression} isInSelectedForests={selectedForests?.indexOf(forest) !== -1}/>);
          })}
      </MapContainer> 
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Error message:

```
    No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>

      42 |       </Provider>);
      43 |   };
    > 44 |   return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
         |                      ^
      45 | };

      at useLeafletContext (node_modules/react-leaflet-draw/dist/react-leaflet-draw.js:319:11)
      at EditControl (node_modules/react-leaflet-draw/dist/react-leaflet-draw.js:358:17)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22779:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293:18)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11327:26
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
      at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11322:9)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11309:3)
      at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23620:3)
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
      at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
      at flushPassiveEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23447:14)
      at Object.<anonymous>.flushWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:992:10)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1107:9)
      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:97:26)
      at renderWithProviders (src/Testing/renderWithProviders.tsx:44:22)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Testing/Containers/ForestMap.test.tsx:15:5)
```

I am using a custom render function as RTL recommends [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/).

```
// test-utils.jsx
import React, { FC, PropsWithChildren, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import { PreloadedState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RootState, AppStore, setupStore } from '../Redux/store';


// This type interface extends the default options for render from RTL, as well
// as allows the user to specify other things such as initialState, store. For
// future dependencies, such as wanting to test with react-router, you can extend
// this interface to accept a path and route and use those in a <MemoryRouter />
interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'> {
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>
  store?: AppStore
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export const renderWithProviders = (
  ui: ReactElement,  
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {},
) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  const Wrapper: FC = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            {children}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>);
  };
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
};
```

All other tests are working as expected.

I have attempted modifying the renderWithProviders function by adding another `<MapContainer>` itself around `children` (below `BrowserRouter`), but this has not worked. I have also attempted to similarly wrap `children` with `LeafletProvider`, but I have not found a passed-in value for its prop `value` that works. My last attempt looked like as follows:

```
interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'> {
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>
  store?: AppStore
  context?: any, // for use with react-leaflet
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export const renderWithProviders = (
  ui: ReactElement,  
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    context = {},
    ...renderOptions
  }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {},
) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  const Wrapper: FC = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <LeafletProvider value={context}>
            {children}
          </LeafletProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>);
  };
  return { store, context, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
```

Comment: What does `ForestMap` look like?  What version of react-leaflet are you using?

Comment: I am using react leaflet version ^3.2.2 (3.2.2 itself is the latest version according to npm). I have added the code for `ForestMap` to the original post.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this? @krallj